# why the name does not exist in the current category?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Trying to generate same code of block with a loop but getting this problem.

Inside the foreach loop the first time I use the var categories I have no problem or error but the second time inside the IMG tag it says "the name does not exist in the current category"

However if I put another tag (a, img , p etc ) after the foreach and before the div with class col-md-4 , then all other uses of var categories is giving the same error "the name does not exist in the current category"

why?

```
@model IEnumerable<MyAPP.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="row">

    @foreach (var categories in Model)

           <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>@Url.Action("Browse", new { categories = categories.CategoryName })</h2>
                <img src="@categories.ImagePath" class="img-responsive" alt="horizontal blids" />
                <p>
                    just text
                </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: where are the `{}` braces of foreach loop?

Comment: Likely the missing braces, also beware of `class` and `@class`

Comment: thanks Khosla  Yes that was the the problem I was missing the {}  I was about to post an answer but saw yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
@model IEnumerable<MyAPP.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="row">

    @foreach (var categories in Model)
{
           <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>@Url.Action("Browse", new { categories = categories.CategoryName })</h2>
                <img src="@categories.ImagePath" class="img-responsive" alt="horizontal blids" />
                <p>
                    just text
                </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
}
```